# Difference between a JavaScript Function() and a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand something in JavaScript which confuses me.

Let's say that I want to create a method `Guard.ThrowError()` in JavaScript, I have 2 approaches for this:

1. Using an object:

   This is basically the approach which I found on the net.

   ```
   var Guard2 = {
     ThrowIfNull: function() {
       throw new Error('sdmflsfk');
     }
   };
   ```
2. Using a Function:

   When you create a class "Guard" in TypeScript and you let it compile to JavaScript, you get something like this:

   ```
   var Guard = (function() {

     function Guard() { }

     Guard.ThrowIfNull = function () {
       throw new Error('sdmflsfk');
     };

     return Guard;
   })();
   ```

Both functions can be called using `Guard.ThrowIfNull()`.
I would like to know what's the difference and when choose I choose approach 1 over approach 2?

Thanks for your valuable feedback.

Kind regards

Comment: internally in javascript is everthing a object even a function or an array.

Comment: @Rajesh: Another good catch, fixed it. (Just under 400 more points of rep and you can fix things directly; meanwhile, you can always do a suggested edit.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to know what's the difference and when choose I choose approach 1 over approach 2?

The only difference is that `Guard` is a function in your second example and not a function in your first. So the second one can be called (in that code it doesn't actually *do* anything, but it can be called); the first can't.

Functions are objects in JavaScript, proper real objects, and so like all other objects, they can have additional properties added to them like your `ThrowIfNull`.

[jQuery](http://api.jquery.com) is a widely-used example of this: The main function, `jQuery` (aka `$`) is used for its function-ness:

```
$("#foo").on("click", function() { /*...*/ });
```

...and also for its object-ness, because it has various properties attached to it exactly as you've done with `Guard`:

```
$.ajax(/*...*/);
```

Comment: Guard does not do anything because it has no constructor? Is that assumption correct? So that means if Guard does not have to be called directly, there is no reason to use the second example?

Comment: @Complexity: No, nothing to do with constructors. `Guard` doesn't do anything because it has no code in it; it's an empty function. But yes, if you're never going to call it, there's no reason for it to be a function, so I'd just use a non-function object (your first example).

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation. I was looking for an implementation of a static class and it sees that this is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Both approach works because a function in javascript is also an object. The only difference is that you can call a function `myFunction();` and you can't do it with a object.

Answer (score 0):

Function approach is used to create classes in JS. Using this approach, you can have private and public properties. This cannot be achieve in object approach. All properties are public in object.

#### Sample Example

```js
function testClass(){
  // Private member
  var a = "abc";
  var b = "test";
  
  
  function print(){
    console.log(a,b);
  }
  
  return {
    print: print
  }
}

testClass().print();
// testClass().a    This will throw error
```

Comment: Downvoter, please put a comment if I'm missing something. Would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

`Guard2`- your approach 1 - is somehow a 'static' definition of an object. You can't instatiate another object of that type.

`Guard`- your approach 2 - is a mixed: it's a definition of an 'automatic class' `Guard` which gets instantiated. The result is almost the same as you can't instantiate new objects from that as well.

Usually, you would do it like this:

```
var Guard = function() {

  function Guard() { };

  Guard.ThrowIfNull = function () {
    throw new Error('sdmflsfk');
  }; 

};

var myGuard = new Guard();
```